# Unable to render MVC Checkbox/Label combo in one horizontal line

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have an **MVC 4** (*Beta*) **View** with the following markup:

```
<div id="ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConsentToMarketingEmails)
    @Html.CheckBoxWithTooltipFor(m => m.ConsentToMarketingEmails, new { type = "checkbox", @checked = "checked" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConsentToMarketingEmails)
</div>
```

Although I've tried many patterns, here is an example of a simple CSS style applied to render the **Label** --> then **CheckBox** in one horizontal line.

```
#ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart
{
    display:inline;
}
```

No matter what I do it always renders as follows in IE9:

[image]

What can I do to make this all render on one line?

***Note***: There is plenty of horizontal space so wrapping should not be an issue.

**UPDATE**

---

The following markup is what currently gets rendered:

```
<div id="ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart">
    <label for="ConsentToMarketingEmails">I consent to Marketing Emails</label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The I consent to Marketing Emails field is required." id="ConsentToMarketingEmails" name="ConsentToMarketingEmails" title="Indicates your willingness to except marketing emails" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="ConsentToMarketingEmails" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConsentToMarketingEmails" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

This now has the following style which appears to work everywhere except IE9:

```
#ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart
{
    display:inline;
}

#ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart label
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That's more of a HTML + CSS question than ASP.NET MVC. Please update your question showing your generated HTML markup and retag it properly.

Comment: Have you tried setting the label style to "display: inline"

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I wasn't sure if somehow this ended up being something unique to the MVC stack, but I take your point. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: @JoeGeeky, that's pure HTML+CSS. Strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. A web browser doesn't know what ASP.NET MVC is. It sees and renders your markup and styles it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem... The Label element had an alternate **display** set at a higher level in the document. In IE9 this translated to the result you saw in the Question. Here was the offending CSS.

```
frameset label 
{ 
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is like this.

```
<div id="ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart">
    <label>@Html.CheckBoxWithTooltipFor(m => m.ConsentToMarketingEmails, new { type = "checkbox", @checked = "checked" }) Checkbox Label </label>        
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConsentToMarketingEmails)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the label to the left:

```
label {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @Darian, would the float have to be cleared in order to display correctly in older versions of IE?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I tried this but it didn't make any difference. Here is the CSS I just tried. `#ConsentToMarketingEmailsPart label
{
    float: left;
}`

Comment: Could you please show your markup? And CSS? Ideally provide a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating your problem.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov As requested, I've added the markup and full style to the question. Also, I tested this in jsfiddler and it works fine there. That led me to test other browsers and it appears this is only an issue for IE 9. That said, I'm still not sure how to resolve it for IE9

Comment: @JoeGeeky, hmm very strange, as this works perfectly fine for me. Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qTnFh/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It works for me also using jsfiddler with IE9. But when hitting the web server locally with IE9 it doesn't work. Locally, when I use any other browser it also works.

Comment: @JoeGeeky, can you then post your full HTML allowing to reproduce the problem? It's obvious that there's something else in your code that you haven't shown that's causing the issue. Ideally update the jsfiddle I have started. Don't forget to include your CSS as well.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'll have to setup an account on jsfiddler to share. I did test the entire HTML and all the styles on jsfiddler and still was not able to recreate the problem using jsfiddler.

Comment: @JoeGeeky, no, you don't need to setup an account. Simply put your HTML and CSS and click on the Save button which will generate you an url that you can share with us.

Comment: Strange, it shows on the same line for me when I open it with IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and found real solution, how to show checkbox and label inline

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

Solution taken from MVC 4 Internet application template.